# jQuery AJAX calls are failing when devtools are opened

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, user-interface

jQuery Ajax calls in our application are failing when I open the dev tools to monitor the API calls. Getting 500 internal error.

If I close the dev tool window, it is working fine.

This is happening on the production server. Where in my local server, it is working fine in both ways.

I tried by starting java profiler to record in chrome it is working. Once I stop it is not working.

When I read the server logs, It is trying to validate the CSRF token where the token is not matching. It is throwing the exception. But still, the confusion that why this error is happening only when debug window is opened.

My Ajax call code is as below:

```
jQuery.ax=function(url, data, async, type, dataType, successfn, errorfn) {
    async = (async==null || async=="" || typeof(async)=="undefined")? "true" : async;
    type = (type==null || type=="" || typeof(type)=="undefined")? "post" : type;
    dataType = (dataType==null || dataType=="" || typeof(dataType)=="undefined")? "json" : dataType;
    data = (data==null || data=="" || typeof(data)=="undefined")? {"date": new Date().getTime()} : data;
    data.avoidCacheDate = new Date().getTime();
    data.AJAXREQUEST = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        beforeSend: function (request){
            getToken(request);
        },
        async: async,
        data: data,
        url: url,
        dataType: dataType,
        success: function(d){
            successfn(d);
        },
        error: function(e){
            errorfn(e);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Well pretty impossible to tell why on our end. So what is the error on the production server? Did you look at the logs?

Comment: Prodution server means the middleware logs you are asking ryt..

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's a caching issue? Your 200 (good) response might be simply cached (you didn't set `cache: false` option in your sample code, which is `true` by default). Chrome DevTools has a checkbox "Disable cache" on the "Network" tab. So when you open DevTools your requests are being really sent to the server (and getting a fresh/actual/real 500 response).

Just add `cache: false` to avoid caching and you will probably always get 500 until fix the problem.

PS: using `avoidCacheDate` data field as a cache buster isn't correct since `data` will be passed to the query sting only in case of "GET" request. For other (like POST or PUT) it will go to the request payload. Use `cache` option for this.

Comment: Hi Roman86,Thanks for the response. To summarize if i set cache to false in the ajax request, it will always throw the 500 error until we fix the issue. But if I close the dev tools window my api returning the data for me. I'm new to the development where adding cache to false to the request for production application will be a good parctice?

Comment: hi @user3093856! in most cases using "cache: false" is the right way, especially when you request some API endpoint and expect fresh data on every request. Caching could be good for some static assets which are changing rarely and don't affect the application's work.

Regarding closed DevTools no error - it's weird. If you've set "cache: false" - there must be always fresh response (500?). Try executing your request in ARC. Or (if it's GET) simply open it in new tab adding some random param to the URL

Comment: Roman, I added cache: false,
        headers: {"Cache-Control": "no-cache", "Pragma": "No-cache"}, but still same behavior. not getting what would be the issue.

Comment: @user3093856 let's clarify - it still returns 200 if no DevTools active? And 500 with DevTools only?

Comment: @user3093856 is it a GET or PUT or POST request? Have you tried to execute it outside of the browser? Like ARC or Curl

Comment: Outside the browser, the request won't work. CSRF security is enabled.

Comment: CSRF token is just a header. You can also simulate it outside the browser: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4xM5PbVNv0

Comment: Thank Roman for your support. When I do request from the externally working fine. Thinking that CSRF is taking the OLD token code. But I added cache false and async: false. But don't know why still reproducing.